# Vim: replacing text within function body

Tags: vim, replace

I have some very useful plugins to find and replace text through files (see `EasyGrep` vim script - it's very helpful for programmers). I can even replace text only in the current buffer - by using plugins or `:%s ...`. But what if I just want replace text within the current function body?

Consider the following example:

```
void f0()
{
     int foo = 0;
     // ...
}

// 99 other functions that uses foo as local variable.

void f100()
{
     int foo = 0;  // I want to replace foo with bar only in this function
     // 1000 lines of code that uses foo goes below
     // ...
}
```

Of course, I can use `:%s ...` with `c` flag for confirmation, but I believe there is a faster way to do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could mark the function with V. Then when you type a command in :, it'll automatically be prefixed by and only be executed in the marked area.

There's probably a command for jumping to beginning of function and end of function, so you could do begin-function, V, end-function, substitute very quickly. Don't know those commands though.

Answer (score 20):

You can apply a substitution to the whole file using `%` or on a selection.

**To create a selection** :

Go in Visual mode Linewise for example, with `Shift+v`, select a few line and then type `:`.

Your prompt will look like :
`:'<,'>` it means : current selection

Type then `s/foo/bar/g` and it will replace foo by bar in the current selected line.

The **better** way to select a function content is to go inside a function with your cursor and type :
`vi}` it will select everything between `{` and `}`.

See `:help text-objects` for more tips on selection.

Comment: Thanks for `vi}`. That's really useful. But when there are blocks `{ ... }` inside the function, `vi}` gets confugsed :(

Comment: @maverick : There are other tricks like using `[[` to jump to `{` in the first column. Once you are there, enter visual mode with `v`, then press `%`. It will jump to the closing `}` and select your function in the process. If it works well for you, you can then remap `[[v%` on a given key to quickly select functions.

Comment: You can also use `[m` to jump to the start of a function/method no matter the number of `{`,`}` that are in the way. I have a created a mapping in my .vimrc file to to use function/method bodies as text-objects. `vnoremap <silent> am :<c-u>normal! [mV]M<cr>` and
`onoremap <silent> am :<c-u>normal! [mV]M<cr>`. Now selecting a function body is as simple as `vam`

Comment: Thanks, I'll use it in my vimrc. Very useful

Answer (score 1):

I've always used [[ to jump to the beginning of the function, then use % to jump to the end of the function. I used **mt** and **mb** to mark the top and bottom of the function, respectively. Then to search and replace within the marked top and bottom, **:'t,'bs/pattern/newpattern/g**. This has always worked for me. I'm sure you can create a macro for this.

The visual select (vi}) is much easier and faster. It is aware of the cursor position. So, if the cursor is inside a fucntion sub block, then vi} selects all lines in that block. If you want to select the entire function, one needs to place the cursor outside of the sub blocks then do vi}. This is great for function blocks that fits in the current window. For functions that spans beyond the current window, the selection is lost once scroll up.

I really like the visual select of the vi} because it's so much easier and faster, but I have to resort the old school method on occasion.